# IOS: dismiss two viewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, dismiss

I have three viewController

First, Second and Third

from Second to open Third I use

```
Third *third = [[Third alloc]initWithNibName:@"Third" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:third animated:YES];
[third release];
```

Now I want return from third to first; then I set in viewDidAppear in second this code:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

but for 1 second I see Second and I don't want watch it...how can I do?

Comment: how second view is added to first view?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to dismiss third view controller first and then second Viewcontroller. Do the following code when you want to go first view controller.

```
-(void)goToFirstView{
        UIViewController *vc = [self parentViewController];
   //     UIViewController *vc = [self presentingViewController]; //ios 5 or later
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        [vc dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

How is the Third modal view being dismissed in the first place?  Perhaps by the user touching a 'Done' button?  If so, it is in the handler for the button that you want to dismiss both.

You can dismiss both as:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
[self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: NO];
```

Comment: I think the **animated** parameters should be NO then YES, see rakeshNS 's answer

Answer (score 0):

This happens coz viewDidAppear is called everytime before the view appears so as soon as it appears you dismiss it and it disappears..

I don't think what u are trying to do can be achieved with modalViewControllers... 
instead use a navigationController and keep adding your viewcontrollers onto the stack and when you want to goto the First view controller just call

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

**`EDIT`:**

just thought of it this can be achieved by using delegation.. you make second the delegate of third and as soon you dismiss the thirdviecontroller send the delegate a message.In this message call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];`..
and you are done.. (pretty easy if you know delegation.)